# Outlook 2013 Appointment through Visual Basic Excel; I want to have an appointment that my calendar says busy and others say free

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar, visual-basic

I'm creating an Excel document with a number of different required settings to make the process of logging vacations and business trips in my company's division easier than the current system.

Currently, I'm stuck on one small part of the assignment and would like some advice. I am creating an email appointment through outlook that will send out a message to the necessary associates to make certain they know but don't have their calendars busy. This task is easy enough, I set the email message to "free" meaning their calendars are not cluttered yet they get informed. Unfortunately I can't seem to find a way to set the requesters calendar to "busy" in the same appointment while the other recipients are free.

I have a round-about solution which is to send two different emails, one busy the other free. The issue is that this method is cluttered and creates too much hassle for the end user when two emails pop up at once. Optionally I could send it without first displaying the information, but then if they mess up the dates it is created without them looking first.

If you can aid in just the Outlook portion then I'll be able to find the solution through VBA, but if you have both that would be kind of you to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to send an appointment with 2 different Status.

You could send the "Free" email only to the coworkers and the "Busy" email only to the requester so you don't get the 2 popup issue but then they would have to be modified separately.

Comment: I figured as much. I appreciate the feedback and have taken the necessary steps to use this solution. Thanks!